# check if it's a number 0 "zero"

Tags: uipath

I'm using a regex code to check if the value of an output code, if it's contains a number 0 (zero)

Btw, i'm using UiPath.

Here's what i did, but when it shows number 1, it sends me true, which it shouldn't!

Code :

> System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch("output_matches(0)","[0]")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing a string with value `"output_matches(0)"` and not the actual content of the first element of the array. Since you have a 0 in that string it will match the regex.

If you simply need to check if `output_matches(0)` is the value `"0"` you can use the `=`-operator: `output_matches(0) = "0"`.

If you need to check if `output_matches(0)` contains a zero you can use `output_matches(0).contains("0")`